# How to retrieve a column in SQL that cannot be GROUPED BY

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

SQLFIDDLE: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a83823/4

I want to retrieve the first book released by each author in the table. I want to run a query that displays the author's name, the title of the earliest book and the year it was released. I tried using the code below but I can see why it is causing an error but I cannot find a way around this. Any help will be appreciated!

```
SELECT author_fname, author_lname, title, MIN(released_year) 
 FROM BOOKS 
 GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Instead of screenshot of the table create minimum working demo. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for example.

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: I think, You should add the `title` column also in `group by` and give the alias name to the aggregated column as `MIN(released_year) AS released_year`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion @ino Here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a83823/4

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @AryanDeora , have you found a suitable solution in any of those 4 answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r.author_fname, 
  r.author_lname, r.released_year, 
  r.title
FROM
 (SELECT author_fname, author_lname, 
      MIN(released_year) AS min_year FROM books
  GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname) l
 JOIN books r
   ON r.author_fname = l.author_fname 
   AND r.author_lname = l.author_lname
   AND r.released_year = l.min_year
```

Should do it. The usual trick is to write a query that selects the max/min/sum from each group and then you perform a join.

Your query

```
SELECT author_fname, author_lname, title, MIN(released_year) 
 FROM BOOKS 
 GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname;
```

is actually illegal! Although there's a MySQL option that allows you to do this sort of stuff but generally it's invalid to select a column that does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Also, if you do select a column that you don't group by then it's value is essentially undefined (although most engines will set it to the first value they see which means you get the value of the row you inserted first). Some installations have this option disabled per default while some seem to have it enabled by default but anyway... **you're not supposed to select a column that does not appear in your GROUP BY clause.**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
select * from books where (author_fname, author_lname, released_year)    
in (select author_fname, author_lname,min(released_year) as year 
from books    
group by author_fname, author_lname)
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be solved using denserank function. check if the following code helps you.

```
with temp as
(
Select author_fname, author_lname, title, denserank() over (partition by author_fname,author_lname order by released_year asc) as bookrank
from books
)

select author_fname, author_lname, title, released_year
from temp
where bookrank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from books 
WHERE (author_fname, author_lname, released_year) IN 
  (SELECT author_fname, author_lname, min(released_year) AS 'earliest year' 
  FROM books 
  GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely because you have the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY function enabled. To fix this, you have to disable it.

Run this command:

mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));